# What is the meaning of the "Pluralize or singularize generated object names" setting?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

When setting up a new Entity data Model, there is an option to

> [x] Pluralize or singularize generated object names

I have noticed this is an option in LINQ as well. Also, now that I am studying the ADO.NET entity framework, I noticed it also has 'DEFAULT' to 'pluralize or singularize generated object names'

What is the result of not checking/allowing this option when setting up the 'Entity Data Model'.

*What Advantages/Disadvantages/issues will I face by making a selection one way or the other?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No problem at all, except that you'll probably want to do it manually. Usually, you want entity names singular and entity set names plural.

Answer (score 10):

If you check `Pluralize or singularize generated object names`, the set in the class `context.cs` genrated by EF will be named in the format:

```
public virtual DbSet<SomeTableName> SomeTableNames { get; set; }
```

if not check, it'll be named:

```
public virtual DbSet<SomeTableName> SomeTableName { get; set; }
```

---

Advantages/Disadvantages IMHO:

I would like to see collection set be named ending with 's', such as dbset colleciton of `Employee class` of `Employee Table` named  `Employees`, so  I'll check the option. But I guess maybe someone would like to treat the dbset as a table, so he/she would like to name it same as table name `Employee`.

Comment: What are the advantage/disadvantages involved?